How to use `external_account` credentials with the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK?
I'm trying to authenticate the Firebase admin SDK in Node.js using Workload Identity Federation credentials with AWS.
Here's the relevant part of my configuration:
{
  "type": "external_account",
  "audience": "//iam.googleapis.com/<identity_pool_provider_identifier>",
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/<service_account_email>:generateAccessToken",
  "token_url": "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token",
  ...
}

The format of this file is specified in AIP-4117.
According to this issue, it is now possible to use credentials of type external_account when using applicationDefault().
I made sure that the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable is populated correctly.
I tried using the following code:
const firebase = admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
      projectId: process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    });

firebase
      .messaging()
      .send({ /* ... notification payload ... */);

... which gives this error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "The caller does not have permission"..
I highly doubt I am missing permissions, since I was using the lower-level google-auth-library client to use Firebase Cloud Messaging, and it worked fine for months.
Now that the Firebase admin SDK supports external account credentials, I wanted to give it a try to be able to use all the features, but I am having this issue.
Anything I might be missing, or doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
